# A value error occurred when using OpenTelemetry in FastAPI

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, open-telemetry

I'm using OpenTelemetry in FastAPI for logging and gunicorn to start the service.

Below is my configuration, I expect it to get the otel fields.

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "disable_existing_loggers": false,
  "root": {
    "level": "INFO",
    "handlers": [
      "access"
    ]
  },
  "formatters": {
    "default": {
      "()": "uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
      "fmt": "[%(asctime)s] [%(name)s] [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s"
    },
    "access": {
      "()": "uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter",
      "fmt": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] [trace_id=%(otelTraceID)s span_id=%(otelSpanID)s resource.service.name=%(otelServiceName)s] - %(message)s"
    }
  },
  "handlers": {
    "default": {
      "formatter": "default",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
      "stream": "ext://sys.stderr"
    },
    "access": {
      "formatter": "access",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
      "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
    }
  },
  "loggers": {
    "": {
      "handlers": [
        "default"
      ],
      "level": "INFO",
      "propagate": false
    },
    "uvicorn.error": {
      "handlers": [
        "default"
      ],
      "level": "INFO",
      "propagate": false
    },
    "uvicorn.access": {
      "handlers": [
        "access"
      ],
      "level": "INFO",
      "propagate": false
    },
    "gunicorn.error": {
      "handlers": [
        "default"
      ],
      "level": "INFO",
      "propagate": false
    },
    "gunicorn.access": {
      "handlers": [
        "access"
      ],
      "level": "INFO",
      "propagate": false
    }
  }
}
```

The above configuration works if I use uvicorn.

However, when I started the service, it showed an error message as shown in the picture. Which value is missing?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u498Y.png)